# Should I create a virtual environment for a framework?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Guys I'm about to install "scrapy" and I was wondering if it would be a good idea to create a virtual environment? I'm also not the expert in doing these types of things, so I would have to research on it before doing anything... but my question still stands should I create one or should I just install it directly "pip3 install scrapy", I ask this because I read somewhere it can conflict with other frameworks, correct me if I'm wrong please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should try to create virtual environments if you have multiple frameworks.

PEP0405 proposes to add to Python a mechanism for lightweight "virtual environments" with their own site directories, optionally isolated from system site directories. Each virtual environment has its own Python binary (allowing creation of environments with various Python versions) and can have its own independent set of installed Python packages in its site directories, but shares the standard library with the base installed Python.

for more information check https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html and 
 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/